# ML/DL Train Model on Single Column Feature DataSet

Tags: machine-learning, deep-learning, neural-network

I am trying to build a model that can predict insurance names based on insurance Id.
Before putting the question to this forum, I have tried KNN and Decian Tree, but the accuracy does not exceed more than 60%.

In my data frame, I have one column as a feature and the other as a label.
I can also extract other features from this data as well like Is Numeric, length, etc.
I have 2.8M rows of data in this shape.

| insurance_id | insurance_name |
| --- | --- |
| XOH830990804 | Medicare |
| XOH01179276 | Medicare |
| H55575577 | Medicare |
| H71096147 | WELLMED |
| IBPW01981926 | BCBS |
| MT25110S | Aetna |
| WXQQ07123 | Aetna |
| 6WU7NSSGY63 | Oxford |
| MX7ZZ35T | Oxford |
| DU00079Z | Welcare |
| PB95800M | UHC |

Please guide me on which approach or model can help me to achieve an accuracy of more than 80%.

Answer (score 0):

You can try to diversify your inputs

As an example, you can pass aditional features to the network, such as:

- Length of the insurance_id
- Quantity of numbers in the insurance_id
- Quantity of letters in the insurance_id
- Sum of all numbers in the insurance_id

And any other transform you might think of.
As the output layer of your network, you might wanna use `Dense(n_of_different_insurance_names, activation='softmax')`
and a `categorical_crossentropy` loss function when compiling the model